# How to ignore escape character while using substr function in R

Tags: r, substr, backslash

There is a string variable x

```
x <- "aa\xbbcc"
```

I want to use

```
y <- substr(x, 1, 3)
```

to extract the first three character "aa\".

However, "\x" is an escape character. Therefore an error message showed:

```
Error during wrapup: invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash'
```

I tried to use

```
x <- gsub("\\", "/", x)
```

to replace "\", but it didn't work and showed:

```
Error during wrapup: invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash'
```

How to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: The first three characters are `aa\xbb`, not aa\ . What exactly do you want to extract?

Comment: what I want is to make "aa\xbbcc" as a 8-character string : "a", "a", "\\", "x", "b", "b", "c", and "c". Therefore I can extract "aa\" out.

Comment: Your string doesn't contain a "\\", "x", or "b" (x2). It contains the character that is _printed on screen_ as "\xbb". Therefore what you want is an ill-posed question.

Comment: I can't control the input x, which is from a database. The x in the database is really a string contain 8 characters and the "\xbb" is not a backslash in the database. However, R recognized "\x" as a backslash, which is not what I want. How to avoid this step, and reserve the "\xbb" as four characters?

Comment: I know while reading "\" string into R, the "\" will be translated to "\\". But in this case, I received "\". I can't find any way to solve it in front-end. Maybe I should solve this problem in back-end (database). Thank you Hong Ooi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\xbb` inserts the ASCII character `>>` into the string. `\xbb` is hexadecimal notation for the decimal value 187. To delete this character, do this:

```
gsub("\xbb","",x)
```

Then you can use `substr` on the resulting string.

Comment: "aa\" , "xbb" and "cc" is meaningful. Therefore "\xbb" can't be replaced. Which is a big problem to me. I've spent whole day on it, but no idea.